# Is a variable silently declared for you by the compiler/runtime when you don't declare one?

Tags: objective-c, compilation, return, local-variables

When I have a method with just a return statement and a value:

```
-(id)doSomethingCool
{
    return [someArray objectAtIndex:2];
}
```

... is the compiler (or runtime) actually adding an intermediate variable behind the scenes:

```
-(id)doSomethingCool
{
    id someObject = [someArray objectAtIndex:2];
    return someObject;
}
```

I'm guessing at the assembly level it might be doing something like this?

I realize this is an obscure and probably performance-insignificant issue for 99% of applications, but I'm still curious what actually happens behind the curtains in Objective-C if anyone knows.

As an aside, is the only reason people do the first technique just for shorthand convenience, even if over tens of millions of iterations it would be no different had they done it the second way?

Comment: I would like to encourage you to not be apologetic about being curious about the inner workings of your tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually, that's basically what happens. The value returned from the function is a temporary value. It's actually a copy of whatever value you're returning, which exists until the expression that the method call is used in finishes.

In practice, when you compile with optimizations turned on (in Release mode), the two examples you give will generate identical object code. The difference between the two is largely just down to style, though explicitly storing values in local variables can be useful in debugging.

Comment: Though, in release mode, local variables may be optimized away.  They may even be reused for other purposes halfway through a method's scope!